# What are Madara Uchiha's weaknesses?

Tags: naruto

At his current state, how could Madara possibly be defeated?

Any physical attack/Taijutsu would be easily deflected by either:

- The Susano'o
- The Gunbai (war fan, which proved to easily negate a Bijuudama)
- Shinra Tensei (which wasn't seen yet, but we have to assume he's capable of it).

> And I'm not even starting to talk about the Rikudo mode.

Any non-physical attack would be easily absorbed by the Preta Rinnegan path. There aren't <s>m</s>any ultra-powerful genjutsu ninja who can hope to trap him in a genjutsu for more than 2 seconds. And in the offshoot that something does hurt him, he'd just regenerate. He's a zombie.

---

What weakness does Madara have that could be exploited to harm him? They'd have to damage him badly to hope for a seal.

Comment: His massive ego is his greatest weakness, his over confidence makes him underestimate the power of others.

Comment: grasshopper has the right of it in his comment!

Comment: @grasshopper: That's a good one. Though I *did* kick the 5 kages' behinds. You should post that as an answer!

Comment: Simple a Senju descendant can beat him, already its been shown in Naruto's lineage he inherits the senju blood him and Kyubbi will put him to rest.

Comment: According to Itachi every jutsu has a weakness, but that may not apply to jutsu combos (Rinnegan EMS Wood release).  However the manga already showed that over-reliance on the Rinnegan's chakra / jutsu absorption is risky with Sage mode nature chakra (risk of turning into a stone statue).

Comment: @jw013: According to Kishimoto, "Every shinobi has a weakness. Madara however, does not.".

Comment: It occurred to me recently that even Edo Madara hasn't developed a would counter to a Sage mode sound-based genjutsu.  The Sage Frog genjutsu gave Pain a hard time despite the Rinnegan - he dealt with it the second time by simply killing the frog before the jutsu could be activated.  Edo Itachi also had difficulty dealing with Kabuto's Sage sound genjutsu and only got out of it because he was facing Sasuke and the pair were able to use Sharingan on each other.

Comment: @jw013: Yeah, lucky for them that they have so many Shinobi who can do that! It's a good point though! Add it as an answer

Comment: Madara is open when switching eye abilities.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It does not seem like any of Madara's new abilities have a counter to sound genjutsu, especially when boosted by Senjutsu / Sage mode.  While sound genjutsu and Senjutsu are both very rare, the manga has shown two examples of different techniques of that type being effective against techniques that Madara has recently gained.

The two Sage Toads' sound genjutsu is effective against the Rinnegan.  When Jiraiya had them use it in his battle with Pain, it was able to easily overcome 3 paths of Pain.

> When Kabuto in Snake Sage mode used Tayuya's flute sound genjutsu, he was able to immobilize both Sasuke and more notably, a Susanoo-wielding Edo Tensei Itachi.  The pair were only able to escape by using Sharingan genjutsu on each other.

Answer (score 8):

Chapters 622 and 623 hint at a possible weakness of Madara Uchiha.

In Chapter 622, it has been shown that Madara has issues with [being too aware of his surroundings, and being easily distracted or have an inability to focus properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjgyn.png). He also has [issues with pride](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwcJz.png), that he carried on until his adulthood.

> [image] 
>  [image]

In Chapter 623, the same possible weaknesses has been shown. [He even claimed that he didn't have any weaknesses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuxX0.png). [[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuxX0.png) [[2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hhrB.png).

> [image]

<sup>Credits: All images are from [Mangastream](http://mangastream.com/)'s scanlations.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

They mentioned in the latest chapter that Madara is vulnerable to Taijutsu.  Also, as grasshopper said, his overconfidence causes him to drop your guard when dealing with those he thinks are not able to harm him.

Comment: No, they said that only those have a chance to hit (because non-physical attacks are 100% useless), so they can **try** to hurt me with Taijutsu. Even Gai's Afternoon Tiger's direct hit didn't really hurt me.

Comment: Heh, chance to hit = vulnerable.  Agreed that it's not exactly exploitable though, the same way your ego is.

Answer (score 3):

> Currently the only combatants I could see do lasting damage to Madara would be the recently resurrected Hokages. Currently Madara has the following: full control of Hashirama´s cells, Rinnegan, an invulnerable body and an infinite supply of chakra (courtesy of the Edo Tensei), the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan and the most powerful Katon of all time. Kishimoto has outright said that he has no real weakness. The closest thing to a weakness he may have is Taijutsu, but since it does no lasting damage it´s frankly as useless as everything else one could use against him. Only an intervention from the 1st-4th Hokage could possibly defeat him right now, as he is a cocktail of the 3rd strongest person of all time and all the overpowered abilities in the series.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not an answer (but couldn't stop writing this), but seeing the question and recent chapter I believe Madara's weakness is:

> Talk No Jutsu .... [**For your reference**](http://konohalibrary.wikia.com/wiki/Talk_No_Jutsu)