# Is sound genjutsu more powerful than eye genjutsu?

Tags: naruto

After going through this [**link**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/76/what-are-madara-uchihas-weaknesses), I came to a belief that sound genjutsu is far more superior to eye genjutsu.

After recalling the incident of the two Sage Toads' genjutsu and Kabuto's genjutsu, I felt that it was difficult for the Sharingan/Rinnegan users to concentrate on their battle.

So is my speculation true?

Some of the sound genjutsu techniques are listed here:

1. [**Demonic Illusion: Toad Confrontation Chant**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Demonic_Illusion:_Toad_Confrontation_Chant)
2. [**Temple of Nirvana Technique**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Temple_of_Nirvana_Technique)
3. [**Demonic Flute:Phantom Sound Chains**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Demonic_Flute:_Phantom_Sound_Chains)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that sound genjutsu is superior. Sound genjutsu operates on a different sense, so that renders doujutsu (eye techniques) useless to escape from it, unlike with illusions that work on vision.

That makes sound based genjutsu more effective on Sharingan users, because they rely on their improved vision powers to counter most genjutsu.

Answer (score 2):

The sound base genjutsu  can be more effective than eye contact base genjutsu cause we have seen might guy fighting itachi without looking into his eyes and no eye contact means no genjutsu but if sound base genjutsu is being used even a skilled opponents can not block or doge the sound waves completely plus its a sound base genjutsu so it depends on the air so it covers most of the effective areas.

Sound base genjutsu are really powerful but some of them cannot be performed simultaneously so this is disadvantage you have 1 shot if you miss that's all.

So in all manners and looking at the all points we can say that there are advantages and disadvantages of eye contact base genjutsu and sound base genjutsu.

That's what I think.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of Madara's answer, sound and smell, maybe taste genjutsu would be most effective, since it doesn't affect the eyes but rather other senses, of which no doujutsu provides advantage to. If Madara were to be blinded, he would still be able to use doujutsu, but his other senses would diminish. This is a time when Orochimaru would come with something useful as he is the Sound Village's leader.

Comment: can u site some smell and taste genjutsu?

Comment: @Jiraiya As far as I know, there haven't been any mentioned or seen in the story. But in theory, if there is visual and sonic genjutsu, then there is most likely smell and taste variation. It's not too inconceivable, as it would be most effective to an opponent, considering a person may be deaf and blind, but everybody must breathe (**except the dead of course**). There's only so long a person can hold their breath, before succumbing to their body functions to passively breathe again.

Comment: your speculation is correct....no doubt about that but since we are dealing with this particular anime,i was expecting some facts with your statement.....no doubt about ur theory,but i was more intersted on the impact it might have against eye techniques

Comment: A ninja from one of the Naruto the movies was using a smell based genjutsu. I forget who. Her jutsu involves petal whirls.